# How many extra digits of precision do we need for $e^1$ so that $(taylor(e^1))^n = taylor(e^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to calculate $e^x$ for a given precision $p$ (that is $error < \frac{1}{10^p}$), using taylor series.

$e^1$ converges pretty quick, so I'm wondering if for calculating $e^x$ (where $x > 1$), calculating bare $e^1$ and then exponentiate the result would be faster than calculating $taylor(e^x)$

I wanted to do some benchmarks, but I understand that I would need extra precision for $e^1$ so that when doing the later exponentiation, I would not accumulate any rounding errors (the greater is $x$, the extra precision I would need, as far as I know)

Is it possible to know how many extra digits of precision I would need for $e^1$ so that it satisfies that for a given precision $p$:

$$(taylor(e^1))^n = taylor(e^n)$$

For example:

With $p = 2$:

$e^1 = 2.72$

$(2.72)^2 = 7.3984$

Which is then rounded to: $7.40$

On the other hand, when calculating $taylor(e^2)$ until we get 2 digits of precision, we get:

$7.387302$

Which is rounded to $7.39$

So $7.40 \neq 7.39$

---

However, If I had used one extra digit of precision for $e^1$ It would have worked:

For example:

With $p = 2$:

$e^1 = 2.718$ (uses extra precision)

$(2.718)^2 = 7.387524$

Which is rounded to $7.39$

---

However, this would not work for greater $x$ since the error gets bigger with the exponentiation.

However, it *may* work with sufficient extra precision digits for $e^1$. If that is true, can I know how many extra digits will I need for a given $x$ and $p$?

Comment: how do you exponentiate the result? Isn't the whole point of this to exponentiate numerically?

Comment: The goal is to being able to calculate $e^x$ for a given precision $p$. And I'm trying to determine which method is faster **A)** To calculate `e^1` and then exponentiate to `x` **B)** Or to use Taylor series for $e^x$. ||| However, the first method *may* not get accurate results since you are exponentiating the error (so the bigger is x, the worse) (AFAIK)

Comment: so by exponentiationg you apply the map $a \mapsto a^x$? My point is that if you know this map then you can also calculate $e^x$ directly... you reduced the problem of exponentiating to exponentiating, which is not very useful... perhaps you rather want to reduce exponentiating to multiplicaiton using taylor series?

Comment: Hi @user159517, I added a couple of examples on my original post. Sorry If I did not make myself clear. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are low integers the only values of $x$ you are interested in? I.e., ones where simply multiplying $e$ by itself $x$ times is a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Hi @PaulSinclair, $x$ is supposed to be a Natural. But it should work with any $x$, whether it is a low or high value. On the example I added, x is low value (2), however, it still does not work (unless using extra precision for $e^1$)

Comment: Use the taylor series for $e^x$. Even if you can get away with multiplication to calculate the exponent, you would need at least as many terms of the series for $e^1$ to calculate $e^x$ to the required precision as are needed of the series for $e^x$ itself, and the calculation is simpler, and doesn't even require $x$ to be integer at all.